# Docker doesn't create directory during build

Tags: docker

Experimenting with Docker for the first time. Have these steps in my Dockerfile to create a directory, but when I run the container, the directory isn't there.

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER AfterWorkGuinness
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
RUN cd /root/.ssh
RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f id_rsa
VOLUME /root
EXPOSE 22
```

**Build image:**

```
docker build -t ubuntu-ssh --no-cache .
```

**Testing the directory when I run the container:**

```
docker run -it -v c:/users/awg/dev/tmp/home:/root ubuntu-ssh

root@39eec8fa51ad:/# cd ~/.ssh
bash: cd: /root/.ssh: No such file or directory

root@39eec8fa51ad:/# cd /root/.ssh
bash: cd: /root/.ssh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do you expect the contents of `/root` to be, given that you're mounting `/users/awg/dev/tmp/home` there?

Comment: I expect a dir ".ssh" to be created and populated with ssh keys as a result of building the docker image.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness - jwodder was trying to say that the directory is being created; but you're mounting over it with your `docker run` command. You're replacing *everything* inside `/root` with `c:/users/awg/dev/tmp/home`

Comment: Ah. I was trying to get those files to stick around after the container is shut down. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a named [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) instead of a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/),

```
docker run -v tmphome:/root whatever
```

In a named volume the files will still persist over container restarts but the contents from the directory [will be copied to the mounted volume at creation time](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container). Docker chooses where to store the data depending on the driver in use. `local` is the default and data defaults to the `volume` directory in the Docker data dir, usually `/var/lib/docker/volumes`