# SSH keys not being created in Docker image

Tags: docker, ssh

Experimenting with Docker for the first time. Trying to create ssh keys when building the container. The build output shows they are created, but I don't see them where I expect them in /root/.ssh. What am I doing wrong?

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER AfterWorkGuinness
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
RUN cd /root/.ssh
RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f id_rsa
EXPOSE 22
```

**Build output:**

```
Step 5/7 : RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
 ---> Running in 373406b5976a
 ---> acb1b7b1a8c0
Removing intermediate container 373406b5976a
Step 6/7 : RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa
 ---> Running in 36ee488a98bd
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:bnm79N/fHIwcbFAH/obiP3nFFPevdo25kECvQzNXfq8 root@36ee488a98bd
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|             o.. |
|            o ...|
|          .. .. +|
|         . .ooo o|
|        S =.o=.=o|
|       . o.*+.=.=|
|        + =.oo.*+|
|       . o +.+===|
|          o..+Eo*|
+----[SHA256]-----+
 ---> d3f23fbf9240
Removing intermediate container 36ee488a98bd
Step 7/7 : EXPOSE 22
 ---> Running in 1381315dad22
 ---> 50e5e6337ee6
Removing intermediate container 1381315dad22
Successfully built 50e5e6337ee6
```

**Running container:**

```
docker run -it -v localTmp:/root ubuntu-ssh
```

**Directory Empty**

```
root@09904a84f312:~/.ssh# cd /root/.ssh
root@09904a84f312:~/.ssh# ls
root@09904a84f312:~/.ssh#
```

Comment: Why are you mounting the localTmp volume over /root where you generated the files?

Comment: I don't want the keys to be wiped when the container restarts. I thought this was the way to make sure contents of the home dir (/root) such as the ssh directory and the keys both created in the build stick around after container restart. Is this wrong?

Comment: The volume mounts storage over the path which essentially causes any I/O to happen in the volume instead.

If you remove the -v option, do you see the files you expect?

Comment: No files but the /root/.ssh directory is still there.

Comment: If the files don't exist, then I would say there was a problem generating them.  The files created during the build will be in the container.

Comment: Try running the same ssh-keygen command from your running docker container and verify the output.

Answer (score 0):

I see you asked the first part of this question over in [Docker doesn't create directory during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821751/docker-doesnt-create-directory-during-build), and that you've tried using a named volume rather than a bind mount to work around this problem.  The only different between a bind mount and a named volume is that *if* the named volume is empty, Docker will copy into it the contents of whatever you're mounting it on top of.  If the named volume had *anything* in it (e.g., because you had previously used it to test things out), you won't see that copy behavior.

But honestly, this is all beside the point: you should be generating ssh keys at *run* time rather than at *build* time.  There are very few situations where you actually want every container deployed from that image to have the same ssh keys.

If you *really* want a bunch of containers using the same ssh keys, then continue generating the keys at build time, but place them somewhere else on the filesystem, and then copy them into `/root/.ssh` at runtime.

In the above, pretty much every time I say "at runtime" I am suggesting the use of an `ENTRYPOINT` script.  You can read more about that [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Comment: I believe you are advocating this:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504187/ssh-key-generation-using-dockerfile)